# Modify moderncv

Tags: moderncv, cv

I'm trying to build a resume based on the modern cv package. However, I'd like to modify a few features (included a photo of my final goal).
I went through the description of the original pacakage but find it dufficult to override the commands for the title, section header (in the original package the subsections have a block on the left side), and subsection header.
Also, I didn't manage to change cventries so that the years will appear on the right hand side (like in the example below).

Any suggestions?
[image: What I'm trying to do. Remarks in green]

Comment: Which style are you using?

Comment: wdym? If I get you correctly, the fonts in the picture are based on \moderncvtheme[red]{classic}. but I built everything manually (i.e. the title and the header aren't generated from commands, so making a long cv in this way will be tedious and probably not effective)

Comment: Please show us a short TeX code without personal informations. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ... Which moderncv style do you use?